# Italics using siunitx

Tags: siunitx, italic

I have been using `\textit` for italic text in my work and also used `\SI` for numbers with units using the `siunitx` package. There is now an instance where I want the number and unit to be in italics, so I've written:

```
\textit{\SI[]{8}{\micro\meter}}
```

But it does not appear in italics. I can't understand from the help documentation which option to use. Any advice? I have not used `\sisetup{}` in the preamble either.

Comment: Why should it? By default siunitx complies to the si guidelines, aka units should always be upright so noone confuses them as variables

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Simply use `\sisetup{detect-all = true}`

See the [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/siunitx/siunitx.pdf) on page 20:

> The siunitx package controls the font used to print output
>   independently of the surrounding material. The standard method is to
>   ignore the surroundings entirely, and to use the current body fonts.
>   However, the package can detect and follow surrounding bold, italic
>   and font family changes.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
    \SI{7}{\metre}

    %Change to detect-all = true
    \sisetup{detect-all = true}
    \textit{\SI{7}{\metre}}

    %Change it back to detect-none = true
    \sisetup{detect-none = true}
    \textit{\SI{7}{\metre}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The documentation also says on page 83:

> The mathematical meaning of units also means that the shape, weight
>   and family are important. Units are supposed to be typeset in an
>   upright, medium weight serif font. Italic, bold and sans serif are all
>   used mathematically to convey other meanings.

Maybe you should think over using italic units

Comment: Thanks, this works.

It was actually part of a table, where the entire row, which includes this \Si information, is all in italics, because it is different from other rows for certain reasons. I will try to think of a better way to do it though, thanks

Comment: @slew123 I would suggest highlighting that row in the table