# Siunitx package wrongly displaying cursive units in math mode

Tags: siunitx

When trying to write units using the siunitx package, they are somehow displayed in cursive. The following code

```
\unit{\candela} \\
\qty{5}{\metre\per\second} \\
$\si{\newton}$ \\
$\unit{\candela}$

% Sort of fix??
\sisetup{detect-all = true}

\unit{\candela} \\
\qty{5}{\metre\per\second} \\
$\si{\newton}$ \\
$\unit{\candela}$
```

results in

[image: Screenshot of output of code. Only the 5th and 6th line are correctly non-cursive.]

The `\sisetup` line is something I found in [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/443027/italics-using-siunitx) thread. It fixes the italics for text mode, but for math mode it still doesn't work.

My guess is that this is the result of some packages conflicting; I'm using a template for my thesis with a lot of packages loaded in for displaying the title page etc. When running the same example in a new document, it seems to work correctly.

I also have a lot of `\newcommand` and `\renewcommand`, but disabling these doesn't resolve the issue, so it is probably something else causing it.

[Here](https://pastebin.com/vmrt7hhE) is a list of the packages I'm using, generated by `\listfiles` (links to pastebin.com)

Comment: Welcome! But please, try to post a complete but minimal program showing the problem. It is impossible to help without it, because you can have conflicting packages, wrong options, whatever, as you say. Please read [this](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)  and prepare a minimal working example (MWE): help us to help you!

Comment: The way to proceed is: copy your complete document to another one. Remove all the text in the body minus the snippet shown here. Start removing things from the preamble: until you have a *minimal* example showing the problem. You can basically using bisection there. Post the result. At that point, be sure that somebody will help you.